# Write a dot instead of a comma when it's last element in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a while loop use to write a list. i'd like every element separated with a comma, but write a dot after the last one, not a coma.
Here is my code

```
$exec = mysql_query($req);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)){
    echo '<strong>'.$row['name'].'</strong>, ';
}
```

But I don't know how to do that. I tried using count() or end(), but none of these works. A little help would be great !

Comment: Accept answer to get reputation

Comment: I did, I was just waiting, cause I can't accept within the first couple of minutes ;)

Comment: @jeni Give it a chance. The question was only 12 minutes old! :)

Comment: @Brendan Bullen i helped him. moreover i cant wait after getting what i actually need. :)

Comment: I have to say, it's only the second time that I ask something on SO, but the answer's time was only always super fast. It's so great !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$html = array();

$exec = mysql_query($req);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)){
    $html[] = '<strong>' . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) . '</strong>';
    // --------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^! (1)
}

$html = implode(', ', $html) . '.';
```

---

(1) - *Never* output data to HTML without escaping it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I like the use the implode function for this :)

```
$list = array();
$exec = mysql_query($req);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)){
    $list[] = '<strong>'.$row['name'].'</strong>';
}
$string = implode(", " , $list);
echo $string . ".";
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$exec = mysql_query($req);
$output = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)){
    $output[] = '<strong>'.$row['name'].'</strong>';
}
echo implode(',', $output), '.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the string but don't output. Then, trim off the command and add a fullstop:

```
$exec = mysql_query($req);
$output = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec))
{
    $output .= '<strong>'.htmlentities($row['name']).'</strong>, ';
}

if($output) echo rtrim($output, ', ').".";
```